# Accessing GPS data with JavaScript in real time

Tags: javascript, gps

Is it possible to access GPS data in real time on a smart phone with JavaScript (without an android or ios application I mean)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes. You are looking for the [Geolocation API](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html), here's [a simple demo](http://html5demos.com/geo). Here is sample code [from Dive Into HTML5](http://diveintohtml5.info/geolocation.html) and [HTML Rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/geolocation/trip_meter/). Works great from web pages hosted on iOS and Android phones, it's a simple API to use. Strictly speaking it's not GPS; it's a generic location API. On mobile devices like iPhones location is often provided by WiFi or cell tower fixes and not the GPS radio.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So, there is no way to force GPS radio location?

Comment: Not via the GeoLocation API, no. Also it doesn't provide GPS-specific information like satellite signal strength, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I've used solution, where Java applet was reading NMEA GPS data from serial port and wrote it to browser's global variable - where it was accessible to JavaScript. It worked well on laptop and regular browser, not sure, how it would work on smartphone.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help.
I wrote html 5 mixed with JavaScript and Ajax (to write data on my website coordinates).
I use Android samsung (2 years old from now on) to do tests.

When a Wifi button is on the wifi connexion works fine I can see longitude and latitude changing (GPS and Data buttons are off).

When GPS and  DATA buttons are on (and wifi button off) geolocation coordinates longitude and latitude are frozzen (no updates)... no change...

one possible anwser can be here found on this answered Jun 6 '13 at 6:51 by Eduardo: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16955512

I tested it, and it worked for me...

Answer (score 0):

I now used "https://github.com/domoritz/leaflet-locatecontrol"...

(And I don't know why the answer body must be at least 30 characters.)